# Interrogative pronouns about animals (Quis aut quid)

Tags: pronouns, interrogative

If I want to ask the question about the dog, whose name is `Cerberus` should I ask

> Quis est Cerberus?

or

> Quid est Cerberus?

Do we use `quis` or `quae` (according to gender) about animals or `quid`?

What is the rule here?

Comment: Welcome to the site! You may ask about me in any way you please, but *quis* would indeed be conventional.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Welcome to the Latin Stack Exchange!

If you are asking "who" Cerberus is, then *Quis* is correct since Cerberus is male. If you want to know "what" Cerberus is, then *Quid* is correct.

Comment: Are you sure that the interrogative pronoun, "quis", is gender-dependent, in the nominative?

Comment: If this answer were correct, Pontius Pilatus should have said: “Quis est veritas?” because *veritas* is feminine. But he famously said “Quid est veritas?”

Comment: @Joonas llmavirta: The interrogative "quis" remains the same for masciline & feminine nominatives; e.g. "quis venit?" = "Who (male or female) is coming?". To specify gender, the adjectival pronoun; "quis homo venit?" = "What man is coming?". The neuter nominative, "quid", may be less useful--"What comes?".

Comment: @SebastianKoppehel I see your point and that makes sense, although because the subject was a proper name, "Cerberus" and one that we know was specifically male, I assumed the question was only asking "who is Cerberus". I'll update my to make that more clear since both words make sense depending on what your question actually is.

Answer (score 7):

*Quis* and *quid* are both grammatical here, but mean different things.

"Quid" is a pronoun meaning "what", and can be used that way even in a sentence with a masculine, feminine or plural subject:

Some examples:

- > Ipsi enim **quid** sumus aut quam diu haec curaturi sumus?

  (Cicero, *Epistulae ad Atticum* 12.11.1.1)
- > **Quid** est enim exsul?

(Cicero, *De Domo Sua* 72.3)

So if you mean to ask "What is Cerberus?"/"Cerberus is what?", you can say "Quid est Cerberus?"

"Quis" means "who", so if you mean to ask "Who is Cerberus?", you can say "Quis est Cerberus".

Compare English: "What is Cerberus" and "Who is Cerberus" are both valid sentences; they just mean different things.

Of course, Latin is not English. But similarly, compare the use in Latin of *id* vs. *is*: I believe *id est Cerberus* and *is est Cerberus* are both grammatically valid. Since a demonstrative pronoun like *is/id* does not have to agree with the gender of the other noun in copular construction, I don't think the interrogative pronoun *quis/quid* has to agree in this construction either.

In terms of grammatical resources, here are some reddit posts I found:

- [Small question about use of Quis, Quae, Quid?](https://www.reddit.com/r/latin/comments/4srn5q/small_question_about_use_of_quis_quae_quid/)
- [LLPSI Exercitium question](https://www.reddit.com/r/latin/comments/b0he3z/llpsi_exercitium_question/)

Also the questions listed in this handout "[Developing oral skills in Latin](http://www.nysed.gov/common/nysed/files/programs/world-languages/latin2.pdf)", from the website of the New York State Education Department, show usage of *quid* vs. *quis* according to the meaning of the pronoun, not in agreement with the other noun in the sentence:

> Ask the following questions
>
> Teacher: Quid est Campus Martius?
>
> Student: est locus
>
> [...]
>
> Teacher: Nunc quid est Spartacus?
>
> Student: gladiator

---

Other alternative interrogative pronouns:

- *Quī,* aside from being used always as the masculine nominative singular relative pronoun, is sometimes used as an interrogative pronoun. So possibly "Qui est Cerberus?" could be used. But I'm not sure if that would be a good choice. Some grammar resources suggest there could be some shade of difference in meaning between *quis* and *quī* in this kind of context: I'm also not sure about that.
- In the unlikely event that you meant to ask something like "Which *[of these women]* is Cerberus?", you could possibly even use "Quae est Cerberus?", with a feminine pronoun. See Brutal Russian's answer here: [Confused about the use of “quae” as an interrogative word](https://latin.stackexchange.com/a/12712/9))